# Basing a file selection on User input in R

Tags: r, file, path

I am rather new to R. I have written code in the past and my script works when I don't add the user input.I have 14 files in each of 2 txt file paths that have to be selected from. Each are specifically paired. the DS01 is paired with VDS1_1.  I see the file path in the environment widow and it lists the files successfully. When I run it, I get no errors. But when I type in the DS01 in the interactive mode, I get the DS01 object does not exist error.

```
{ 
  askUser <- readline(prompt="Please, enter the data set (1-14) using DS# format:   ")
      SCpathname <-"E:/DS_textfiles/"
      list.files(path = SCpathname, pattern = "txt")
      VDSpathname <<-"E:/VDS/"
      list.files(path = VDSpathname, pattern = "txt")
       # to show the path works and files are there
  print(askUser) 


if (askUser== DS01){

   SCfilename =  "DS01.txt"
   VDSfilename = "VDS1_1.txt"
   SC120000 <- read.table(file=SCfilename, header=FALSE)
   VDS      <- read.table(file=VDSfilename, header=TRUE)

  }else if (askUser== DS02){
       SCfilename = " DS02.txt" 
       VDSfilename = "VDS2_1.txt"
       SC120000 <- read.table(file=SCfilename, header=FALSE)
       VDS      <- read.table(file=VDSfilename, header=TRUE)         

}else if (askUser== DS03){
     SCfilename = " DS03.txt" 
     VDSfilename = "VDS3_1.txt"
                SC120000 <- read.table(file=SCfilename, header=FALSE)
                VDS      <- read.table(file=VDSfilename, header=TRUE)     

   }else if (askUser==DS04 ){

       SCfilename = " DS04.txt" 
        VDSfilename = "VDS4_1.txt"
        SC120000 <- read.table(file=SCfilename, header=FALSE)
        VDS <- read.table(file=VDSfilename, header=TRUE)     

}else {
  return("Choose a different file number")
}
}
```

Comment: `readline` returns a string, so I suspect all the `*` in `askUser == *` should be quoted

Comment: I will try that and update

Comment: So I did add the "" to the askUser entries, and now I get an rt error. Does rt not do tab delim data?

Comment: If by `rt` you mean `read.table`, yes, it reads TSVs. What error are you getting?

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection but when I do the list files, it is there in the path . Do I need to add choose.file or file.choose?

Comment: Print out the filename you're passing and see if it matches. `file.choose` will open a file chooser dialog window and return a path, which is a different option, but not convenient for two files.

Comment: Thank you for your help with the "" portion. I was able to fix the problem by setwd for each one. Now I just need to collapse this giant if-then-else in a tidy couple of lines

Comment: Use `paste0` to make the filenames